# Update PHP via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, session

I have a javascript code that basically displays a box that says that you will be logged out within 60 seconds if you dont click on the link. Now my question is can I use that link with a JavaScript onClick event to somehow update my php code that detects if your session is older than 30 mins.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minates ago
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the runtime
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Short of refreshing the includes.php file is there anything else that I can do to update my $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] variable?

Comment: why not save a cookie that expires in 30 minutes, and then you check if that cookie exists?

Comment: @Simon we are working with some clients that it would be easier to use sessions than cookies, I had already considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use ajax

I'd suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for that.

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $("#result").load('check.php');
});
```

To update variable, use

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
```

Comment: Don't use the load function if you don't want to load content. I suggest a simple `$.ajax({ url: "check.php"});`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session_cache_expire();` and put that before `session_start();`